# Images/Imagebuttons in SharePoint sandboxed Webpart

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, web-parts

New to developing for Sharepoint Online but I'm familiar with how to deploy/package web parts to both local Sharepoint and Sharepoint Online.

Trying to create a basic webpart that contains numerous image links or image buttons to run various links to different libraries and functions. The webpart will activate fine but what I'm struggling with is getting the images to display once deplyed to Sharepoint Online.

If I include the image in the web part solution and deploy it to the local Sharepoint, the image displays correctly but when packaged and uploaded the image won't display. I've googled a fair bit and tried different ways of adding the image as embedded resources in the Web Part package .wsp but none seem to work.

I know I can only make the web part in sandboxed form for use with Sharepoint online, so I can map to the Sharepoint images folder, and really need the image/icon files to be packaged with the .wsp.

Do i need to include the image files in a specific location within the solution for them to be packaged and referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the images through a [module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231567.aspx)

`Url` can be any document library.

```
<Module Name="Pics" Url="PathToDocLib">
   <File Path="yourPicture.png" Url="Pics/yourPicture.png" />
</Module>
```

Comment: When answering questions it is always helpful to add a bit of explanation.

Comment: Will this work in a sandboxed solution? As when it is uploaded it cannot access or write to the file system? I will try this though, otherwise would I need to deploy the images to the document library manually?